# Passing ParcelableArrayList and LongArray to new activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an `ArrayList`  of `Locaiton` and an `Array` of `long` which I am trying to pass to a new activity which will then write them to a file.

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
Intent i = new Intent(Begin_Run.this, GPSTrackDetails.class);
Times = convertLong(times);
b.putParcelableArrayList("Locations", locations);
b.putLongArray("Times", Times);
i.putExtra("bundle", b);
startActivity(i);
```

This is how I am adding them to the `Intent` using a bundle. But when I try to print them out in the new activity I get a null pointer exception.

This is how I am taking them out of the `Bundle` in the new activity.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
locations = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("Locations");
times = bundle.getLongArray("Times");
```

The LogCat output is

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fyp.run_race/com.fyp.run_race.GPSTrackDetails}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.fyp.run_race.GPSTrackDetails.onCreate(GPSTrackDetails.java:37)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are not passing the information correctly. The extended data ("extra") in the Intent *is a bundle*. What you are doing, is putting your bundle *inside that bundle*, under the key "bundle".

If you really want to pass information like you do in your first code fragment, you'll need to get it out via

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable( "bundle" );
```

However, you'll likely just want to put it directly into the extra's, using something like

```
Intent i = new Intent(Begin_Run.this, GPSTrackDetails.class);  
Times = convertLong(times);  
i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Locations", locations);  
i.putExtra("Times", Times);  
startActivity(i);
```